# Mount USB Drive on Esxi 6.5 Host

Tags: vmware-esxi, centos7, mount, vmware-esx

I have ESXI 6.5 (No Center / Sphere), Installed Centos 7 as guest VM.

I want to mount my usb drive in centos 7 to share it with samba on network.

But ESXI doesn't seems to work in my satiation

```
[root@271:/vmfs/volumes] lsusb
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 03f0:7d40 Hewlett-Packard 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1058:1042 Western Digital Technologies, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 0e0f:8002 VMware, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 0e0f:8002 VMware, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 0e0f:8003 VMware, Inc.
```

Here `Hewlett-Packard` and `Western Digital Technologies, Inc.` are my usb and drives.

ESXI WEB UI is greyed out on usb option

[image: ESXI WEB UI]

Please help me out to mount these drive in centos VM .

Comment: vm close = option still grayed out ?

Comment: What do you mean ?

Comment: did you closed the vm before try to add the usb adapter

Answer (score 2):

I rebooted VM and ESXI node.

**Go to settings specified to VM > Add another device >> USB DEVICE >> Select Mounted Device**

[image: USB Added to VM]

It was that simple and there is no simple guide on internet about this.